# How to pass data from a laravel form with a Vuejs component, select tag not working

Tags: php, html, laravel, select, vuejs2

I have a form used to post product in a shopping cart, I have a Vuejs component setup and it retrieves data just fine, but when I try adding a select tag, I can't pass the data from it.
Here's my code for the blade.php file:

```
    <form action="{{ url('/cart') }}" method="POST" class="side-by-side">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" v-model="this.id" value="{{ $product->id }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" v-model="this.name" value="{{ $product->name }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="price" v-model="this.price" value="{{ $product->price }}">
```

{{-- Can't figure out how to pass the following --}}

```
<select  v-model="selected"  required>

            <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
            @foreach($product->withOptions() as $option)
            <option value="{{ $option->options }}">{{ $option->options }}</option>
            @endforeach

 </select>
 <addToCart :product="{{ $product }}"></addToCart>
```

and here's my vue file:

```
export default {
    props: ['product'],

        data() {
            return {
                id: this.product.id,
                quantity: 1,
                name: this.product.name,
                price: this.product.price,
                selected: ''  // always null, can't figure it out
        }
    },

    methods: {
        addtocart() {
            axios.post('/cart/', this.$data)
            .then(flash(this.product.name + ' was added to cart'));
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved that way:

```
<addToCart :product="{{ $product }}" :selected="selected"></addToCart>
```

And in the vue file :

```
 export default {
    props: ['product', 'selected'],

        data() {
            return {
                id: this.product.id,
                quantity: 1,
                name: this.product.name,
                price: this.product.price,
                options: this.selected
        }
    },

    watch: {
        selected: function() {
            return this.options = this.selected
        }
    },

    methods: {
        addtocart() {
            axios.post('/cart/', this.$data)
            .then(flash(this.product.name + ' was added to cart'));
        },
```

Just added a watcher thing.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<select  v-model="selected"  required>
    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
   <option v-for="option in product" v-bind:value="product.option">{{product.option}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your blade.php file

```
<addToCart :product="{{ $product }}" :selected="selected" ></addToCart>
```

Now in your Vue component, you can access the value of selected like this

```
 export default {
    props: ['product','selected'],

        data() {
            return {
                id: this.product.id,
                quantity: 1,
                name: this.product.name,
                price: this.product.price,
                selected: this.selected 
           }
        },
        methods: {
          addtocart() {
            self= this;
            axios.post('/cart/',{
                id : self.id,
                quantity: self.quantity,
                name: self.name,
                price: self.price,
                selected: self.selected
             })
            .then(function (response) {
               console.log(response.data);
            })
           .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            })  
          }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this lets me select it, but it still doesn't gets sent  with the post request tho, the option just stays null..

Comment: @Laurent since you are getting selected in your vue component I updated the methods sections. Please try again. Note that you cannot use this directed inside axios which is already inside a method. So i refer this with self.

Comment: I tried it again, turned it in many many different ways, no luck yet.. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Laurent please confirm that you are getting selected prop in your component and your current problem is with posting datas to server

Comment: @Laurent i edited the answer and please try again. And if axios post not working give the console log error report

Comment: I confirm my problem is posting the data to server, everything is going as it should except this component. I'm gonna try again now

Comment: The data property "selected" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead.
found in
---> <Addtocart> at /home/laurent/public_html/webcreation/resources/assets/js/components/addToCart.vue
       <Root>   This is the error I get when passing this as a prop

Comment: @Laurent change the name of prop to something else and you solve the problem.